# how to look for items in one list from another list in java

Tags: java, list, iteration

I have 2 lists, i'm iterating list1.. if the current item in list1 exists in list2 then i need to make a change in the property of list1.

The lists are just list of objects:

```
list1 = [ObjectVO, ObjectVO]
list2 = ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

where ObjectVO.getId() would return a string such as 'w', ...'z'

My code is as follows:

```
Iterator it = list1.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    objVO = (ObjectVO) it.next();
    if(list2.contains(objVO.getId()){
        objVO.setFlag(true);  
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the the objVO.setFlag(true) is being executed always! like list2 contains all items in list 1 but that's not true, list 2 is only a subset of list1 so it shouldn't evaluate to true for all of them.

How do I fix this or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: can you post the equals method in objVO class ?

Comment: There's no equal method for that object, i'm trying to compare two strings. the one that results from objVO.getId() and the list2 which is an list of Strings

Answer (score 3):

why not just iterate the second list?,

```
for(ObjectVO objVO : list2){
    objVO.setFlag(list1.contains(objVO.getId()));
}
```

Comment: I already have a loop iterating list1 so adding a second iteration given that this can be accomplished during the first iteration doesn't seem good to me... if there's no choice i guess i'll have to but... why would list2 always say it contains all codes when they don't?

Comment: Also just to point out that the list name was interchanged, i've corrected them so this is actually what i'm doing, traversing the object list and see if list1 has it

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the second list to the same datatype so it's comparable and the use Apache Commons collections to find the intersection. Just put all the ObjectVO.getId() into one list.

```
Collection intersection = CollectionUtils.intersection(a, b);
```

Comment: why use a third party library for such a simple task?

Comment: I mean you usually have guava and something from apache commons always included in your project and the code is cleaner.

Comment: I do have the library and I wouldnt mind using it but again, i'll have to iterate over one list to make them objects, then do that call and then iterate again to set the value of the property to false... too much hassle but good to know about this function